# Not able to import my own python package after pip installation

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to build my first python package public available but I'm having some trouble with installing it on another machine, not sure what is wrong. My project is [here](https://github.com/otaviocv/spin).

After all the CI steps on the master branch, Travis publishes the latest version to the [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/spin-clustering/). After that, we can install the package in any place:

```
pip install spin-clustering
```

But when I try to import it on my regular python it says that the module does not exist.

```
$ python -c "import spin"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spin'
```

My package was originally called "spin" but the name was already taken on pypi, I changed it to "spin-clustering", but as scikit-learn is imported with "sklearn" I thought that would be possible to import my package as "spin". Not sure what I'm missing here.

This is my package structure:

```
├── LICENSE
├── Makefile
├── Pipfile
├── README.md
├── examples
│   ├── circle-example.ipynb
│   └── random-cluster-example.ipynb
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── spin
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── distances
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── distances.py
    │   └── tests
    │       └── __init__.py
    ├── neighborhood_spin.py
    ├── side_to_side_spin.py
    ├── tests
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── test_spin.py
    │   └── test_utils.py
    └── utils.py
```

And my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name="spin-clustering",
      maintainer="otaviocv",
      maintainer_email="otaviocv.deluqui@gmail.com",
      description="SPIN clustering method package.",
      license="MIT",
      version="0.0.3",
      python_requires=">=3.6",
      install_requires=[
          'numpy>=1.16.4',
          'matplotlib>=3.1.0'
          ]
      )
```

Comment: Before putting anything on PyPI, you should test locally by installing from the file path to your code, into a sandbox (virtualenv).

Comment: Sure, I will be more careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your setup.py, you [also need to specify what packages will be installed](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-setup-py). The simplest way is using the provided `find_packages` function, which will scan your folders and try to figure out what the packages are (in some slightly unusual cases, your project organization will make this not work right). Your code imports `find_packages`, but is not using it.

Since you have none listed, nothing is actually installed (except the requirements, if missing).

Comment: It worked just fine, but I don't get what this find_package function is doing.

Comment: It looks at the contents of folders in your project, and tries to determine what the packages are (I don't know the specifics). Not every sub-folder in your source directory necessarily represents a package, after all. You might have one for documentation, or tests, or supplementary data.